# MySQL error #1075 - Incorrect table definition

Tags: mysql

Почему?

SQL-запрос:

```
ALTER TABLE  `media` CHANGE  `id`  `id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Ответ MySQL:

```
#1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
```

**Обновление**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `media` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cat_id` int(9) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `info` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `dt` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: в phpMyAdmin жмешь на ключик напротив строки с твоим id, потом ставишь A_I

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ну вполне ж понятно написано..
Только одна колонка может быть с атрибутом auto_increment и она должна быть объявлена ключом (index or primary key)

Answer (score 5):

```
ALTER TABLE  `media` CHANGE  `id`  `id` INT( 11 ) primary key AUTO_INCREMENT
```